# changing timeout jaydebeapi with Denodo driver

Tags: jdbc, jaydebeapi, denodo

I am connecting to a database using a quite standard syntax.

How to change the default timeout value here?

Does it need to be set at the driver or at the jdbc level?

jaydebeapi documentation does not mention that.

Source for jaydebeapi-connection.py

https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/How%20to%20connect%20to%20Denodo%20from%20Python%20-%20a%20starter%20for%20Data%20Scientists?category=Northbound+Connections

```
   ## script name: jaydebeapi-connection.py

## Importing the main library used to connect to Denodo via JDBC
import jaydebeapi as dbdriver

## Importing the gethostname function from socket to
## put the hostname in the useragent variable
from socket import gethostname


# Connection parameters of the Denodo Server that we are connecting to
denodoserver_name = "denodoserver"

# This is the standard port for jdbc connections
denodoserver_jdbc_port = "9999"

denodoserver_database = "distributed_tpcds"

denodoserver_uid = "tpcds_usr"

denodoserver_pwd = "tpcds_usr"

denododriver_path = "/opt/denodo/8.0/tools/client-drivers/jdbc/denodo-vdp-jdbcdriver.jar"

## Create the useragent as the concatenation of
## the client hostname and the python library used
client_hostname = gethostname()
useragent = "%s-%s" % (dbdriver.__name__,client_hostname)

## Creating a variable with the connection uri. We add here the UserAgent
## so the query can be better identified on the server. To append parameters you
## can use the syntax <param_name>=<param_value> and separate them with '&'.
## The full list of accepted parameters is available here
## https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/7.0/vdp/developer/
##        access_through_jdbc/parameters_of_the_jdbc_connection_url/
##        parameters_of_the_jdbc_connection_url
conn_uri = "jdbc:vdb://%s:%s/%s?userAgent=%s" % (denodoserver_name,
                                                            denodoserver_jdbc_port,                                                                         denodoserver_database,
                                                            useragent)
                                                                                           
cnxn = dbdriver.connect( "com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver",
                              conn_uri,
                              driver_args = {"user": denodoserver_uid,
                                             "password": denodoserver_pwd},
                              jars = denododriver_path
                              )

## Query to be sent to the Denodo VDP Server
query = "select * from bv_store_returns"

## Define a cursor and execute the results
cur = cnxn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)

## Finally fetch the results. `results` is a list of tuples,
## If you don't want to load all the records in memory,
## you may want to use cur.fetchone() or cur.fetchmany()
results = cur.fetchall()

# >> len(results)
# 287514
# >> type(results)
# list
# >> type(results[0])
# tuple
# >> results[0]
# (2451794, 40096, 1, 7157, 910283, 6421, 37312, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it via changing the JDBC driver configuration (adding the driver parameter 'queryTimeout') or via the CONTEXT clause of the query itself (https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/latest/en/vdp/vql/queries_select_statement/context_clause/context_clause)